# How to setup a dropdown menu for choosing shipping zone in checkout woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am working currently in a website for a restaurant. The thing is that, they need allow the users to choose a shipping zone during the checkout.

So, in this case the shipping zones configuration from woocommerce does not work as they expect. The main goal is to allow the customers to choose from a dropdown menu, the shipping zone and add the tax via ajax to the total.

I've found a snippet in another site that could be the solution, moreover it is a radio button field and I would need a select dropdown menu.

I've tried to transform the snippet but I did not work.

Could someone have a look and tell me if it's possible to accomplish that ?

I attach the snippet I've found.

I've tried with a lot of plugins already.
I've added the code to the functions.php file

There are not error messages.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice' );



function bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice() {

   $chosen = WC()->session->get('radio_chosen');
   $chosen = empty( $chosen ) ? WC()->checkout->get_value('radio_choice') : 
   $chosen;
   $chosen = empty( $chosen ) ? 'no_option' : $chosen;

   $args = array(
   'type' => 'radio',
   'class' => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
   'options' => array(
      'option_1' => 'Zone 1 ($1000)',
      'option_2' => 'Zone 2 ($2000)',
      'option_3' => 'Zone 3 ($2500)',
      'option_4' => 'Zone 4 ($3500)',
   ),
   'default' => $chosen
   );

   echo '<div id="checkout-radio">';
   echo '<h3>Choisissez votre zone de livraison !</h3>';
   echo '<div class="radio-options">';
   woocommerce_form_field( 'radio_choice', $args, $chosen );
   echo '</div>';
   echo '</div>';

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_fee', 20, 1 );

    function bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_fee( $cart ) {

      if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

      $radio = WC()->session->get( 'radio_chosen' );

      if ( "option_1" == $radio ) {
       $fee = 1000;
      } elseif ( "option_2" == $radio ) {
       $fee = 2000;
      }elseif ( "option_3" == $radio ) {
        $fee = 2500;
      }elseif ( "option_4" == $radio ) {
        $fee = 3500;
      }
      $cart->add_fee( __('Option Fee', 'woocommerce'), $fee );

    }

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_refresh' );


function bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_refresh() {
if ( ! is_checkout() ) return;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        $('form.checkout').on('change', 'input[name=radio_choice]', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var p = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'woo_get_ajax_data',
                    'radio': p,
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}



add_action( 'wp_ajax_woo_get_ajax_data', 'bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_set_session' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_woo_get_ajax_data', 'bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_set_session' );

function bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_set_session() {
    if ( isset($_POST['radio']) ){
        $radio = sanitize_key( $_POST['radio'] );
        WC()->session->set('radio_chosen', $radio );
        echo json_encode( $radio );
    }
    die();
}
```

Comment: Any help on this ? mainly I need to transform this radio buttons in a select dropdown menu. I tried this , by changing 'type' => 'radio', to 'type' => 'select', but then it is not addinng the price of the selected option as it does with the radio button.